# how to connect to PostgreSQL using a stable way

Tags: postgresql

Now I am install PostgreSQL 13 in remote cloud server and expose the 5432 port to public network. I add a whitle list in PostgreSQL config file `pg_hba.conf` like this:

```
host    all             all             127.113.122.1/24           scram-sha-256
```

which `127.113.122.x` is my public ip address of my network, but the problem is the ip address always change when I restart the Router or other reason. When the IP changed, I have to login into remote server and change the PostgreSQL config file and remove the old ip and add new ip. It make me crazy, I have to change the IP of PostgreSQL config again and again, is there any way to connect PostgreSQL using a stable way? both secure and easy to connect.

Comment: Use a VPN or a jump server may be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick a very good password and then don't share it with any other accts and don't leak it.   Hackers generally break into cloud postgresql servers by guessing crappy passwords, not by guessing good ones.  Then open up pg_hba to everyone, or at least the entire range of your isp.

Better yet, do this only for your nonsuper user acct, and block your superuser acct from connecting except for locally.

Comment: I want to open source my code so sometimes the password should not be secure,I could not relay on the strong password. @jjanes

Answer (score -2):

This will let all ip adresses starting with 127.113.122

```
host    all             all             127.113.122.0/24           scram-sha-256
```

This will let all ip addresses starting with 127.113

```
host    all             all             127.113.0.0/24           scram-sha-256
```

And this will let all ips connect database using scram

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0           scram-sha-256
```

Comment: You do not answer my question bro, I know what you say, but I want to know how to connect PostgreSQL a secure way even the ip changed. @Burak Yurdakul

Comment: @Dolphin: specifying an IP _range_ **is** one way to do that. In your question you state that your IP is coming from the range 127.113.122.x and this is what the first example will allow. So that does answer the question as written - maybe you wanted to hear something different, but it's a viable solution. The "*or at least the entire range of your isp*"  - from the answer you accepted is what this answer describes.